# Android 4.3 KeyStore - chain == null while trying to retrieve keys

Tags: android, rsa, android-4.3-jelly-bean, android-keystore

Following [this blog](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2013/08/credential-storage-enhancements-android-43.html), I'm using this code to create and store a `KeyPair` in Android KeyStore:

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
Calendar notBefore = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar notAfter = Calendar.getInstance();
notAfter.add(1, Calendar.YEAR);
KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(ctx).
setAlias(RSA_KEYS_ALIAS).setSubject(
  new X500Principal(String.format("CN=%s, OU=%s", 
    getApplicationName(), ctx.getPackageName()))).
setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE).
setStartDate(notBefore.getTime()).setEndDate(notAfter.getTime()).build();

KeyPairGenerator kpGenerator;
try {
    kpGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");

    kpGenerator.initialize(spec);
    kpGenerator.generateKeyPair();
} catch (Exception e) {
    showException(e);
}
```

When I try to retrieve public key from the KeyStore using this code, a `NullPointerException` with the message `chain == null` is thrown.

```
public RSAPublicKey getRSAPublicKey() {
    RSAPublicKey result = null;
    try {
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore");
        keyStore.load(null);
        KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = 
            (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(RSA_KEYS_ALIAS, null); // --< exception is thrown here
        result = (RSAPublicKey) keyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey();
    }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        showException(e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The same goes with the the code to retrieve private key.

**Update:**

I compared my code with [Google BasicAndroidKeyStore sample](http://developer.android.com/samples/BasicAndroidKeyStore/src/com.example.android.basicandroidkeystore/BasicAndroidKeyStoreFragment.html). The mechanism to generate, store and retrieve the key pair in that sample is virtually the same to what I've implemented. I'm puzzled as to why this code has stopped functioning after a few months of perfectly working.

Any suggestions or hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently names in Android KeyStore must be unique amongst all Apps. I had another app which used the same name for its keys. After changing the the common library used by both apps to create and and use keys to include package name in its key names, the problem went away...

Comment: Just to clarify -- the issue occurred when retrieving the key, not when generating it. So the chain == null was happening when you tried to retrieve the key from a different app than which one generated it?

Comment: I know it is an old post, but do you have any reference that says alias should be unique amongst all apps?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had multiple calls to obtain the KeyStore at nearly the same time. I had to create a single instance and refer to that if it existed, otherwise `KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")` returned `null` and raised an Exception.
To protect against multiple async requests causing a crash, use a stored instance from just one `KeyStore.getInstance()`.

Comment: I had this issue on Android 5 only. I saw this answer and thought... no, surely not. So I tried every other answer, to no avail, and came back to this one in desperation. And what do you know, it worked perfectly! I guess the issue has been fixed in newer Android versions. Don't underestimate this!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was trying to get public key before generating it. (`getRSAPublicKey()` called before `generateKeyPair()`)