# Chain is null when retrieving private key

Tags: android, private-key, android-keystore, android-security

I'm encrypting data in my app using a RSA keypair that I am storing in the Android keystore.

I've been seeing `NullPointerException`s in the Play Store, but I have not been able to reproduce them:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: chain == null
    at java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry.<init>(KeyStore.java:1205)
    at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry(KeyStoreSpi.java:374)
    at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry(KeyStore.java:644)
    at MyClass.getKeyStoreEntry(MyClass.java:111)
```

The source code to create the key pair

```
Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
start.setTimeInMillis(0);
Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
end.set(Calendar.YEAR, 3000);

KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder keySpecBuilder = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
    .setAlias(keyName)
    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=" + keyName))
    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
    .setKeySize(RSA_KEY_SIZE);

KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = keySpecBuilder.build();
KeyPairGenerator gen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
gen.initialize(spec);
gen.generateKeyPair();
```

And then to retrieve the key:

```
private KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry getKeyStoreEntry() {
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ANDROID_KEY_STORE);
    keyStore.load(null);

    if (!keyStore.containsAlias(keyName)) {
        throw new KeyNotFoundException();
    }
    return (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStore.getEntry(keyName, null);
}
```

This is only happening when I make use of the `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` on API level 19-22. The 23+ implementation works fine.

I [do not have another key with the same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23977407/android-4-3-keystore-chain-null-while-trying-to-retrieve-keys) and I also have not [deleted the key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094464/android-keystore-issue-keystore-getentryalias-null-returns-null-sometimes).

Comment: @RED_ no - I ended up falling back to the older implementation if it failed

Comment: Were you ever able to solve this? Having the same issue and it's frustrating!

Comment: nope, I worked around the issue

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are simply facing Keystore bugs. See this article for example: [Android Security: The Forgetful Keystore](http://doridori.github.io/android-security-the-forgetful-keystore/#sthash.19wVBg3j.ZJ8A2Czb.dpbs). There are also numberous bug reports in Android tracker related to keystore, like [AndroidKeyStore deleted after changing screen lock type](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61989).

Comment: I put workarounds in for that place (if the key does not exist in the keystore I recreate it), so this is unfortunately not the issue

Answer (score 1):

Please use directly getKey method of KeyStore

```
private java.security.Key getSecretKey(Context context) throws Exception {
  return keyStore.getKey(XEALTH_KEY_ALIAS, null);
}
```

Comment: this is an RSA keypair, not a secret key unfortunately